# Count number of-cells in a range that match the content of a different cell

Tags: excel

sorry i'm a novice i'm trying but failing here to show a count, say if all cells match based on another column with matching cells then return a 1, if they don't match show as 0..can someone help? sorry if i haven't explained well! eg i have one column showing 3 rows to the left the same, another column showing progress, 2 sent for comments and 1 in progress, then a column showing count for sent for comments so in this case 2 of the 3. how could i show in a formula that it is only a 1 if all the statuses are sent for comments? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add an example to show what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is as in the image below, then in `Cell E2` enter the following formula

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,D2)
```

Change range as per your data. See image for reference.

[image]

You can also use,

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"Sent for comments")
```

for counting `Sent for comments` and

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4,"In progress")
```

for `In progress`.

Comment: Sorry i didnt explain it very well, say if the entries in data (column a) are the same ie row_1 has 3 entries in column a and progress is 1 for sent for comments (i have a formula in another cell to show 1 if its sent for comments and 0 for anything else), then if sent for comments (1) occurs for 1 or 2 of the row_1 entries to return 0 but if all 3 are sent for comments (3 1s, 1 for each row_1) then it shows as 1..ie if all duplicated occurences in column a are sent for comments then return a 1, if not return 0.

Comment: @Adam - Try  '=If((Sumproduct(($A$1:$A$3="row_1")*($B$1:$B$3="Sent for comments"))=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$4,"row_1")),1,0)'

Comment: @Adam - Replying from mobile so above formula is not tested.

Comment: hi guys, thanks but i still don't think that will work, is there some way I can post a screenshot here?

Comment: the row_1 is hypothetical and not as per my data, they are filenames which i have split per system, i.e FINAL ETOP_ABB_3001D_RMU-89101-001-2-3 has 3 systems so i want to send the 3 systems for comments, so  FINAL ETOP_ABB_3001D_RMU-89101-001-2-3 will be listed 3 times. Each one will be sent seperately for comments, only when all 3 systems are sent for comments should it count as 1 but if only 1 or 2 are sent for comments it should remain a 0...

Comment: so can noone help me :(

Comment: @Adam - If you can post some sample data and desired output in the question you are more likely to get answers because as of now your requirement is not clear.

Comment: How do I post data here? Or put a screenshot?

Comment: In the meantime I will try and explain more clearly..I have one file, it has 3 systems associated to it so it is listed 3 times. Once I have sent all 3 systems for comments I want it to count as 1 as the 1 file has been sent for comments and is complete. So I have currently 1 merged cell for the file and 3 single cells for the systems but I would like it to know when all systems are sent for comments so that I don't need a merged cell, it just counts as 1 once all systems for that filename are sent for comments...not so easy I know but maybe someone can help!